# Derivative of elementwise operation

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

I was trying to take the derivative of $$1^T((AA^T) \circ (AA^T))1$$ with respect to $A$, where $A$ is a $m$ by $n$ matrix. I was trying to use the chain rule, but it doesn't work and I know the derivative will have dimension $m$ by $n$, but I cannot get this result. Are there anyone who knows how to approach this question?

Comment: If $1, 1^T$ are the identity matrices, the multiplication by those matrices is useless. Unless those are not the identity matrices. If so, what are they?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I suspect they are vectors of 1s. Now, OP, you can definitely use the chain rule. You have to differentiate the composition $X \mapsto a^\intercal X^2 a$ with $X = AA^\intercal$ with respect to $A.$

Comment: What does $\circ$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$For ease of typing, define the all-ones matrix
$J=\o\o^T,\,$ the symmetric matrix $S=AA^T,\,$  and the Frobenius $(:)$ product $-$ which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
and (conveniently) commutes with the Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
(A\circ B):C &= A:(B\circ C)
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the cost function.
Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= \BR{(S\circ S)\o}:\o \\
 &= (S\circ S):J \\
 &= S:S \\
d\phi &= 2S:dS \\
 &= 2S:(dA\,A^T+A\,dA^T) \\
 &= 2(S+S^T):(dA\,A^T) \\
 &= 4S:(dA\,A^T) \\
 &= 4AA^TA:dA \\
\grad{\phi}{A} &= 4AA^TA \\\\
}$$